# Ext.NET Pivot Grid implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, ext.net

Pivot grid is part of extjs http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/pivotgrid/simple.html
how I can implement that in Ext.NET 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, a Pivot Grid component has been excluded from ExtJS 4 since ExtJS 3 (at least, currently). It is also not included in Ext.NET. The best I can suggest for now is to look at [this UX](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?237492).

Maybe, at some point, we will have enough resources to bake a pivot grid direct in Ext.NET, but I can't promise and can't provide you with any time frame.